# How to use onSensorChanged sensor data in combination with OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix, rotation, sensors

**( edit: I added the best working approach in my [augmented reality framework](https://github.com/bitstars/droidar) and now also take the gyroscope into account which makes it much more stable again: [DroidAR framework](https://github.com/bitstars/droidar) )**

I have written a TestSuite to find out how to calculate the rotation angles from the data you get in `SensorEventListener.onSensorChanged()`.
I really hope you can complete my solution to help people who will have the same problems like me. Here is the code, I think you will understand it after reading it.

Feel free to change it, the main idea was to implement several methods to send the orientation angles to the opengl view or any other target which would need it.

method 1 to 4 are working, they are directly sending the rotationMatrix to the OpenGl view.

method 6 works now too, but I have no explanation why the rotation has to be done y x z..

all other methods are not working or buggy and I hope someone knows to get them working.I think the best method would be method 5 if it would work, because it would be the easiest to understand but i'm not sure how efficient it is. the complete code isn't optimized so I recommend to not use it as it is in your project.

here it is:

```
/**
 * This class provides a basic demonstration of how to use the
 * {@link android.hardware.SensorManager SensorManager} API to draw a 3D
 * compass.
 */
public class SensorToOpenGlTests extends Activity implements Renderer,
  SensorEventListener {

 private static final boolean TRY_TRANSPOSED_VERSION = false;

 /*
  * MODUS overview:
  * 
  * 1 - unbufferd data directly transfaired from the rotation matrix to the
  * modelview matrix
  * 
  * 2 - buffered version of 1 where both acceleration and magnetometer are
  * buffered
  * 
  * 3 - buffered version of 1 where only magnetometer is buffered
  * 
  * 4 - buffered version of 1 where only acceleration is buffered
  * 
  * 5 - uses the orientation sensor and sets the angles how to rotate the
  * camera with glrotate()
  * 
  * 6 - uses the rotation matrix to calculate the angles
  * 
  * 7 to 12 - every possibility how the rotationMatrix could be constructed
  * in SensorManager.getRotationMatrix (see
  * http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_anglestoaxes.html#anglestoaxes for all
  * possibilities)
  */

 private static int MODUS = 2;

 private GLSurfaceView openglView;
 private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
 private ByteBuffer indexBuffer;
 private FloatBuffer colorBuffer;

 private SensorManager mSensorManager;
 private float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];
 private float[] accelGData = new float[3];
 private float[] bufferedAccelGData = new float[3];
 private float[] magnetData = new float[3];
 private float[] bufferedMagnetData = new float[3];
 private float[] orientationData = new float[3];

 // private float[] mI = new float[16];

 private float[] resultingAngles = new float[3];

 private int mCount;

 final static float rad2deg = (float) (180.0f / Math.PI);

 private boolean landscape;

 public SensorToOpenGlTests() {
 }

 /** Called with the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
  openglView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
  openglView.setRenderer(this);
  setContentView(openglView);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
  // Ideally a game should implement onResume() and onPause()
  // to take appropriate action when the activity looses focus
  super.onResume();
  openglView.onResume();

  if (((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
    .getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation() == 1) {
   landscape = true;
  } else {
   landscape = false;
  }

  mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager
    .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
  mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager
    .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD),
    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
  mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager
    .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  // Ideally a game should implement onResume() and onPause()
  // to take appropriate action when the activity looses focus
  super.onPause();
  openglView.onPause();
  mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
 }

 public int[] getConfigSpec() {
  // We want a depth buffer, don't care about the
  // details of the color buffer.
  int[] configSpec = { EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16, EGL10.EGL_NONE };
  return configSpec;
 }

 public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

  // clear screen and color buffer:
  gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  // set target matrix to modelview matrix:
  gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
  // init modelview matrix:
  gl.glLoadIdentity();
  // move camera away a little bit:

  if ((MODUS == 1) || (MODUS == 2) || (MODUS == 3) || (MODUS == 4)) {

   if (landscape) {
    // in landscape mode first remap the rotationMatrix before using
    // it with glMultMatrixf:
    float[] result = new float[16];
    SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix,
      SensorManager.AXIS_Y, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X,
      result);
    gl.glMultMatrixf(result, 0);
   } else {
    gl.glMultMatrixf(rotationMatrix, 0);
   }
  } else {
   //in all other modes do the rotation by hand
   //the order y x z is important!
   gl.glRotatef(resultingAngles[2], 0, 1, 0);
   gl.glRotatef(resultingAngles[1], 1, 0, 0);
   gl.glRotatef(resultingAngles[0], 0, 0, 1);
  }

  //move the axis to simulate augmented behaviour:
  gl.glTranslatef(0, 2, 0);

  // draw the 3 axis on the screen:
  gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
  gl.glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, colorBuffer);
  gl.glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indexBuffer);
 }

 public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
  gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
  float r = (float) width / height;
  gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
  gl.glLoadIdentity();
  gl.glFrustumf(-r, r, -1, 1, 1, 10);
 }

 public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
  gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
  gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
  gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
  gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
  gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

  // load the 3 axis and there colors:
  float vertices[] = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
  float colors[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1 };
  byte indices[] = { 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3 };

  ByteBuffer vbb;
  vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
  vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
  vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
  vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
  vertexBuffer.position(0);

  vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(colors.length * 4);
  vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
  colorBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
  colorBuffer.put(colors);
  colorBuffer.position(0);

  indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length);
  indexBuffer.put(indices);
  indexBuffer.position(0);
 }

 public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
 }

 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

  // load the new values:
  loadNewSensorData(event);

  if (MODUS == 1) {
   SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelGData,
     magnetData);
  }

  if (MODUS == 2) {
   rootMeanSquareBuffer(bufferedAccelGData, accelGData);
   rootMeanSquareBuffer(bufferedMagnetData, magnetData);
   SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null,
     bufferedAccelGData, bufferedMagnetData);
  }

  if (MODUS == 3) {
   rootMeanSquareBuffer(bufferedMagnetData, magnetData);
   SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelGData,
     bufferedMagnetData);
  }

  if (MODUS == 4) {
   rootMeanSquareBuffer(bufferedAccelGData, accelGData);
   SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null,
     bufferedAccelGData, magnetData);
  }

  if (MODUS == 5) {
   // this mode uses the sensor data recieved from the orientation
   // sensor
   resultingAngles = orientationData.clone();
   if ((-90 > resultingAngles[1]) || (resultingAngles[1] > 90)) {
    resultingAngles[1] = orientationData[0];
    resultingAngles[2] = orientationData[1];
    resultingAngles[0] = orientationData[2];
   }
  }

  if (MODUS == 6) {
   SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelGData,
     magnetData);
   final float[] anglesInRadians = new float[3];
   SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, anglesInRadians);
   //TODO check for landscape mode
   resultingAngles[0] = anglesInRadians[0] * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[1] = anglesInRadians[1] * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[2] = anglesInRadians[2] * -rad2deg;
  }

  if (MODUS == 7) {
   SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelGData,
     magnetData);

   rotationMatrix = transpose(rotationMatrix);
   /*
    * this assumes that the rotation matrices are multiplied in x y z
    * order Rx*Ry*Rz
    */

   resultingAngles[2] = (float) (Math.asin(rotationMatrix[2]));
   final float cosB = (float) Math.cos(resultingAngles[2]);
   resultingAngles[2] = resultingAngles[2] * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[0] = -(float) (Math.acos(rotationMatrix[0] / cosB))
     * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[1] = (float) (Math.acos(rotationMatrix[10] / cosB))
     * rad2deg;
  }

  if (MODUS == 8) {
   SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelGData,
     magnetData);
   rotationMatrix = transpose(rotationMatrix);
   /*
    * this assumes that the rotation matrices are multiplied in z y x
    */

   resultingAngles[2] = (float) (Math.asin(-rotationMatrix[8]));
   final float cosB = (float) Math.cos(resultingAngles[2]);
   resultingAngles[2] = resultingAngles[2] * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[1] = (float) (Math.acos(rotationMatrix[9] / cosB))
     * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[0] = (float) (Math.asin(rotationMatrix[4] / cosB))
     * rad2deg;
  }

  if (MODUS == 9) {
   SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelGData,
     magnetData);
   rotationMatrix = transpose(rotationMatrix);
   /*
    * this assumes that the rotation matrices are multiplied in z x y
    * 
    * note z axis looks good at this one
    */

   resultingAngles[1] = (float) (Math.asin(rotationMatrix[9]));
   final float minusCosA = -(float) Math.cos(resultingAngles[1]);
   resultingAngles[1] = resultingAngles[1] * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[2] = (float) (Math.asin(rotationMatrix[8]
     / minusCosA))
     * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[0] = (float) (Math.asin(rotationMatrix[1]
     / minusCosA))
     * rad2deg;
  }

  if (MODUS == 10) {
   SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelGData,
     magnetData);
   rotationMatrix = transpose(rotationMatrix);
   /*
    * this assumes that the rotation matrices are multiplied in y x z
    */

   resultingAngles[1] = (float) (Math.asin(-rotationMatrix[6]));
   final float cosA = (float) Math.cos(resultingAngles[1]);
   resultingAngles[1] = resultingAngles[1] * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[2] = (float) (Math.asin(rotationMatrix[2] / cosA))
     * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[0] = (float) (Math.acos(rotationMatrix[5] / cosA))
     * rad2deg;
  }

  if (MODUS == 11) {
   SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelGData,
     magnetData);
   rotationMatrix = transpose(rotationMatrix);
   /*
    * this assumes that the rotation matrices are multiplied in y z x
    */

   resultingAngles[0] = (float) (Math.asin(rotationMatrix[4]));
   final float cosC = (float) Math.cos(resultingAngles[0]);
   resultingAngles[0] = resultingAngles[0] * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[2] = (float) (Math.acos(rotationMatrix[0] / cosC))
     * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[1] = (float) (Math.acos(rotationMatrix[5] / cosC))
     * rad2deg;
  }

  if (MODUS == 12) {
   SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(rotationMatrix, null, accelGData,
     magnetData);
   rotationMatrix = transpose(rotationMatrix);
   /*
    * this assumes that the rotation matrices are multiplied in x z y
    */

   resultingAngles[0] = (float) (Math.asin(-rotationMatrix[1]));
   final float cosC = (float) Math.cos(resultingAngles[0]);
   resultingAngles[0] = resultingAngles[0] * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[2] = (float) (Math.acos(rotationMatrix[0] / cosC))
     * rad2deg;
   resultingAngles[1] = (float) (Math.acos(rotationMatrix[5] / cosC))
     * rad2deg;
  }
  logOutput();
 }

 /**
  * transposes the matrix because it was transposted (inverted, but here its
  * the same, because its a rotation matrix) to be used for opengl
  * 
  * @param source
  * @return
  */
 private float[] transpose(float[] source) {
  final float[] result = source.clone();
  if (TRY_TRANSPOSED_VERSION) {
   result[1] = source[4];
   result[2] = source[8];
   result[4] = source[1];
   result[6] = source[9];
   result[8] = source[2];
   result[9] = source[6];
  }
  // the other values in the matrix are not relevant for rotations
  return result;
 }

 private void rootMeanSquareBuffer(float[] target, float[] values) {

  final float amplification = 200.0f;
  float buffer = 20.0f;

  target[0] += amplification;
  target[1] += amplification;
  target[2] += amplification;
  values[0] += amplification;
  values[1] += amplification;
  values[2] += amplification;

  target[0] = (float) (Math
    .sqrt((target[0] * target[0] * buffer + values[0] * values[0])
      / (1 + buffer)));
  target[1] = (float) (Math
    .sqrt((target[1] * target[1] * buffer + values[1] * values[1])
      / (1 + buffer)));
  target[2] = (float) (Math
    .sqrt((target[2] * target[2] * buffer + values[2] * values[2])
      / (1 + buffer)));

  target[0] -= amplification;
  target[1] -= amplification;
  target[2] -= amplification;
  values[0] -= amplification;
  values[1] -= amplification;
  values[2] -= amplification;
 }

 private void loadNewSensorData(SensorEvent event) {
  final int type = event.sensor.getType();
  if (type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
   accelGData = event.values.clone();
  }
  if (type == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
   magnetData = event.values.clone();
  }
  if (type == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION) {
   orientationData = event.values.clone();
  }
 }

 private void logOutput() {
  if (mCount++ > 30) {
   mCount = 0;
   Log.d("Compass", "yaw0: " + (int) (resultingAngles[0])
     + "  pitch1: " + (int) (resultingAngles[1]) + "  roll2: "
     + (int) (resultingAngles[2]));
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't test the code yet (but I will, looks really interesting). One thing that caught my attention is that you don't seem to *filter* the sensor data in any way.

Sensor readings are **very noisy** by nature, specially the magnetic sensor. I'd suggest you implement some low pass filtering.

See my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935759/android-accelerometer-difficulties/13936140#13936140) for further reading.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to test and debug Method 5 using GLU's lookAt function: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml

Also, as villoren suggested it's good to filter your sensor data, but it wouldn't really cause bugs if you move de device slowly. If you want to try, a simple one would be as follows:

```
newValue = oldValue * 0.9 + sensorValue * 0.1;
oldValue = newValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

After analyze your code above, in method 5 you are assigning the orientation data as follows,

```
resultingAngles[1] = orientationData[0]; // orientation z axis to y axis
resultingAngles[2] = orientationData[1]; // orientation x axis to z axis 
resultingAngles[0] = orientationData[2]; // orientation y axis to x axis
```

You have done rotation in y z x manner. Try to change the orientation..

I think it might be the problem there.. Please check and let me know..

Please refer the documentation for the event values,
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html

Thanks for your tough work..

Comment: It will be helpful if you explain why its not working fine before and what are the changes you made.. Thanks for your contribution..

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are getting consistently wrong readings, you may have to calibrate your compass, by moving it with your wrists in a figure 8.

Hard to explain this in words; watch this video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sP3d00Hr14o

Comment: I recommend to shake your phone like crazy (watch out you don't loose it;), the 8 movement often didn't work with my g1. additionally the compass i think will only recalibrate if i gets abnormal values, so moving the device slowly in a 8 figure wont help

Answer (score 0):

You can use and-engine for Using sensors with OpenGL Just check the example 
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/tree/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/app/cityradar

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Sensor fusion demo app](https://bitbucket.org/apacha/sensor-fusion-demo) which uses different sensors (gyroscope, rotation-vector, accelerometer + compass, etc.) and renders the outputs from the onSensorChanged-events as a coloured cube that rotates accordingly to your phone.

The results from those events are [stored as quaternions and rotation matrices](https://bitbucket.org/apacha/sensor-fusion-demo/src/182a3034e5f7b305bf00356c9968a59b9a364d64/src/org/hitlabnz/sensor_fusion_demo/orientationProvider/RotationVectorProvider.java?at=master) and used in [this class](https://bitbucket.org/apacha/sensor-fusion-demo/src/182a3034e5f7b305bf00356c9968a59b9a364d64/src/org/hitlabnz/sensor_fusion_demo/CubeRenderer.java?at=master#cl-92) which OpenGL.