# Use the camera of Android device for background of the activity

Tags: android, android-camera, augmented-reality

Since I was having a hard time using the Augmented Reality Example of AndEngine. I thought of doing it my own way. I want to access my Android device's camera and use it as a background in my activity. It still is like an augmented reality. I will be adding sprites later on. What will be the code for the JAVA and XML? Are there any changes in the manifest? THANK YOU!

Comment: I think your question should be more concrete, start with reading camera tutorial http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Answer (score 3):

you have to use camera background(tutorial [**here**](http://ibuzzlog.blogspot.tw/2012/08/how-to-use-camera-in-android.html)) and put sprites with help of some rendering library.I use [**Jpct-ae**](http://jpct.net/jpct-ae/) ,which is very easy to integrate and have a great [**forum**](http://www.jpct.net/forum2/index.php?board=3.0).
and for more augmented reality effect you can apply sensor values to sprites ques [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881128/how-to-use-onsensorchanged-sensor-data-in-combination-with-opengl)

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use camera control API's along with something called a surfaceView to do wat you need. Here are resources to get you started:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android_augmented-reality/
http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/42482
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/cameradirect.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html

good luck!