# Are there simple AR SDK that does not use image recognition?

Tags: android, ios, augmented-reality

I'm looking for a 'basic' AR SDK that allows me to draw images and 3D shapes around the user (no matter where he is). It would be even better if the SDK includes a simple way to detect interaction with the shapes (something like onClick).

I made a project from scratch on Android but there's still a lot of work to do and I'll need to do the same on iOS after... So that's why I'm looking for an SDK or a similar project (no matter what platform).

I tested Metaio but it's quite expensive and maybe overkill for my purpose because it uses LLA coordinates.

I tested DroidAR on Android but it's only for Android and it looks heavy too (don't need the GPS).

Comment: Just to be clear, if you want no image recognition, no tracking and no GPS, what do you expect to use? Only the accelerometer?

Comment: Yes, that's the reason why I called it 'basic' AR SDK.

Comment: I'm looking for a 'basic' AR SDK that allows me to draw images and 3D shapes around the user. I don't need the GPS to draw a virtual scene around the user.

Comment: Yes it is and I'm looking for an SDK to do this (if there's one). I have something working for Android (no interactions yet) but since I'll need to port that to iOS an SDK that does both would be great.

Answer (score 0):

How about Qualcomm's [Vuforia](https://developer.qualcomm.com/mobile-development/mobile-technologies/augmented-reality)?  I was able to quickly get a sample project running on it.

**EDIT** Looks like I was wrong about what it could do.  According to [this](http://augmentedtomorrow.com/tag/qualcomm/) (which is slightly dated, so who knows) Metaio might be your only choice.

Comment: It's an image recognition AR SDK no ? I'm explicitly not looking for that

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I thought it did other things beside that. Edit:  Nevermind, it looks like I was wrong.

Comment: I browsed the samples yesterday and they where all about image tracking so I didn't go further

Answer (score 0):

i really don't sure what you really want to do ..but if you simply show images or 3d models on camera without any detection you can achieve this very easily i am explaining for Android and you can extend it to ios on same logic.

**first approach:**

you have to use custom camera of Android in your app,then use any game engine as per your need..i will suggest [Jpct-ae](http://www.jpct.net/jpct-ae/) or [Rajawali](http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2011/08/23/announcing-rajawali-an-opengl-es-2-0-based-3d-framework-for-android/)
they are very simple to integrate and can be used for 2d images and 3d models.
this [tutorial](http://www.jpct.net/forum2/index.php/topic,1586.0.html) will explains a lot

keep the gl-surafce transparent and you can have model floating in space ...

**second approach :**
to add some more effect to your AR app you can use sensor values to move model in 3d space as per movement of device..it gives a cool effect.

use first approach and additionally collect sensor values and apply that matrix to gl camera of your game engine..for sensor values follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881128/how-to-use-onsensorchanged-sensor-data-in-combination-with-opengl)
good tutorial [here](http://www.jpct.net/forum2/index.php/topic,1666.0.html)..

i hope this may help you..i done these a long time ago but try to help if you want..

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check that when I got some time